# How to define next button using tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I had made a music player where I want to make a `next button` but I can't able to define the button.

The functionality of the `next button` is to play the next song in the same directory and stop the current song from playing.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Here is my code:

```
nexticon= tk.PhotoImage(file=__file__+ '/../images/JPEG, PNG/icons/next.png')

def next(event=None):
    pass

nextBtn = Button(root, bg='#310A3D', image=nexticon, command=next)
nextBtn.place(x=650, y=500, relwidth=.04, relheight=.08)
```

Comment: you may want to loop over each file in directory while adding to the list then use files from the list in a for loop by getting their index and `next()` would play song in the list of `current_index + 1`

Comment: Sir, how I get the current_index of current playing song

Comment: list index of the song read my comment